# Array of polymorphic objects

Tags: c++, arrays, reference, polymorphism, smart-pointers

I commonly come across the need to create arrays or vectors of polymorphic objects. I'd usually prefer to use references, rather than smart pointers, to the base class because they tend to be simpler.

Arrays and vectors are forbidden from containing raw references, and so I've tended to use smart pointers to the base classes instead. However, there is also the option to use `std::reference_wrapper` instead: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/reference_wrapper

From what I can tell from the documentation, this is what one of its intended uses is, but when the topic of arrays containing polymorphic objects comes up, the common advice seems to be to use smart pointers rather than `std::reference_wrapper`.

My only thought is that smart pointers may be able to handle the lifetime of the object a little neater?

TL:DR; Why are smart pointers, such as `std::unique_ptr` seemingly preferred over `std::reference_wrapper` when creating arrays of polymorphic objects?

Comment: If the objects are owned somewhere else, `reference_wrapper` is fine. However, if this container owns the objects and controls their lifetime, you must use a smart pointer such as `unique_ptr` - `reference_wrapper` does not provide any ownership semantics.

Comment: unique_ptr manages the lifetime of the owned object, reference_wrapper stores a pointer to the object. Use unique_ptrs to guarantee the release of the object!

Comment: a reference is just a reference, someone still needs to take care of the lifetime of the objects. With a smartpointer you get all you need at once

Comment: Thanks guys this makes sense.

Comment: actually you already have the answer in your question. The only thing to add is that it is not about "neater", but references dont handle the lifetime at all

Comment: `std::reference_wrapper` as a container element type doesn't offer any advantages over a regular dumb pointer, except that the reference wrapper cannot be null.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

In very simple terms:

- `unique_ptr` is the owner of the object. It manages the lifetime of the owned object
- `reference_wrapper` wraps a pointer to an object in memory. It does **NOT** manage the lifetime of the wrapped object

You should create an array of `unique_ptr` (or `shared_ptr`) to guarantee the release of the object when it's not needed anymore.

Comment: Try to always use smart pointers when you deal with objects that live in the heap. I use pointers like you do when I need to deal with polymorphism but I always try to not use pointers at all!

Answer (score 4):

If you are sufficiently motiviated, you can write a `poly_any<Base>` type.

A `poly_any<Base>` is an `any` restricted to only storing objects that derive from `Base`, and provides a `.base()` method that returns a `Base&` to the underlying object.

A very incomplete sketch:

```
template<class Base>
struct poly_any:private std::any
{
  using std::any::reset;
  using std::any::has_value;
  using std::any::type;

  poly_any( poly_any const& ) = default;
  poly_any& operator=( poly_any const& ) = default;

  Base& base() { return get_base(*this); }
  Base const& base() const { return const_cast<Base const&>(get_base(const_cast<poly_any&>(*this))); }

  template< class ValueType,
    std::enable_if_t< /* todo */, bool > =true
  >
  poly_any( ValueType&& value ); // todo

  // TODO: sfinae on ValueType?
  template< class ValueType, class... Args >
  explicit poly_any( std::in_place_type_t<ValueType>, Args&&... args );  // todo

  // TODO: sfinae on ValueType?
  template< class ValueType, class U, class... Args >
  explicit poly_any( std::in_place_type_t<ValueType>, std::initializer_list<U> il,
          Args&&... args ); // todo

  void swap( poly_any& other ) {
    static_cast<std::any&>(*this).swap(other);
    std::swap( get_base, other.get_base );
  }

  poly_any( poly_any&& o ); // todo
  poly_any& operator=( poly_any&& o ); // todo

  template<class ValueType, class...Ts>
  std::decay_t<ValueType>& emplace( Ts&&... ); // todo
  template<class ValueType, class U, class...Ts>
  std::decay_t<ValueType>& emplace( std::initializer_list<U>, Ts&&... ); // todo
private:
  using to_base = Base&(*)(std::any&);
  to_base get_base = 0;
};
```

Then you just have to intercept every means of putting stuff into the `poly_any<Base>` and store a `get_base` function pointer:

```
template<class Base, class Derived>
auto any_to_base = +[](std::any& in)->Base& {
  return std::any_cast<Derived&>(in);
};
```

Once you have done this, you can create a `std::vector<poly_any<Base>>` and it is a vector of value types that are polymorphically descended from `Base`.

Note that `std::any` usually uses the small buffer optimization to store small objects internally, and larger objects on the heap.  But that is an implementation detail.

Answer (score 1):

Basically, a `reference_wrapper` is a mutable reference: Like a reference, it must not be null; but like a pointer, you can assign to it during its lifetime to point to another object.

However, like both pointers and references, **`reference_wrapper` does not manage the lifetime of the object**. That's what we use `vector<uniq_ptr<>>` and `vector<shared_ptr<>>` for: To ensure that the referenced objects are properly disposed off.

From a performance perspective, `vector<reference_wrapper<T>>` should be just as fast and memory efficient as `vector<T*>`. But both of these pointers/references may become dangling as they are not managing object lifetime.

Answer (score 1):

Let's try the experiment:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <memory>
#include <functional>

class Base {
public:
   Base() {
     std::cout << "Base::Base()" << std::endl;
   }

   virtual ~Base() {
     std::cout << "Base::~Base()" << std::endl;
   }
};

class Derived: public Base {
public:
   Derived() {
     std::cout << "Derived::Derived()" << std::endl;
   }

   virtual ~Derived() {
     std::cout << "Derived::~Derived()" << std::endl;
   }
};

typedef std::vector<std::reference_wrapper<Base> > vector_ref;
typedef std::vector<std::shared_ptr<Base> > vector_shared;
typedef std::vector<std::unique_ptr<Base> > vector_unique;

void fill_ref(vector_ref &v) {
    Derived d;
    v.push_back(d);
}

void fill_shared(vector_shared &v) {
    std::shared_ptr<Derived> d=std::make_shared<Derived>();
    v.push_back(d);
}

void fill_unique(vector_unique &v) {
    std::unique_ptr<Derived> d(new Derived());
    v.push_back(std::move(d));
}

int main(int argc,char **argv) {

   for(int i=1;i<argc;i++) {
      if(std::string(argv[i])=="ref") {
    std::cout << "vector" << std::endl;
    vector_ref v;
        fill_ref(v);
    std::cout << "~vector" << std::endl;
      } else if (std::string(argv[i])=="shared") {
    std::cout << "vector" << std::endl;
    vector_shared v;
    fill_shared(v);
    std::cout << "~vector" << std::endl;
      } else if (std::string(argv[i])=="unique") {
    std::cout << "vector" << std::endl;
    vector_unique v;
    fill_unique(v); 
    std::cout << "~vector" << std::endl;
      }
   }
}
```

running with argument shared:

```
vector
Base::Base()
Derived::Derived()
~vector
Derived::~Derived()
Base::~Base()
```

running with argument unique

```
vector
Base::Base()
Derived::Derived()
~vector
Derived::~Derived()
Base::~Base()
```

running with argument ref

```
vector
Base::Base()
Derived::Derived()
Derived::~Derived()
Base::~Base()
~vector
```

Explanation:

- **shared**: Memory is shared by different parts of the code. In the example, the `Derived` object is first owned by the `d` local var in the function `fill_shared()` and by the vector. When the code exits the scope of the function object is still owned by the vector and only when the vector goes finally away, the object is deleted
- **unique**: Memory is owned by the unique_ptr. In the example, the `Derived` object is first owned by the `d` local var. However it must be *moved* into the vector, transferring the ownership. Same as before, when the only owner goes away, the object gets deleted.
- **ref**: There's no owning semantics. The object is created as a local variable of the `fill_ref()` function, and the reference to the object can be added to the vector. However, the vector does not own the memory and when the code goes out of the `fill_ref()` function, the object goes away, leaving the vector pointing to unallocated memory.